# Arrow functions only have access to initial state created by useReducer, not updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to access the updated state from useReducer inside of an arrow function in a functional component.  However, when I call the state, I'm only getting the initial state object.

The reducer function

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE':
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.progress.request]: action.progress
            }

        case 'REMOVE':
            const { [action.progress.request]: value, ...rest } = state
            return rest

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

The react component

```
const ProgressProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {})

    const start = (request) => {
        console.log(state) // expected to see updated state, but instead see initial value
        // ... do more things
    }


    const end = (request) => {
        console.log(state)
        // ...do more things
    }

    return (
        <ProgressContext.Provider value={{ state, start, end }}>
            {children}

        </ProgressContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

could be used in an api request like this:

```
const progress = useContext(ProgressContext)

const getData = async params => {
    const url = '/my/endpoint'
    progress.start(url)
    try {
        await axios.get(url, { params })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    } finally {
        progress.end(request)
    }
}
```

I expect in the start and end functions to be able to see an updated state, but I actually see the initial state `{}`

Comment: When are `start` & `end` called and how & where?

Comment: @SungM.Kim, I edited the post to show a useful example.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `state` to change, you need to `dispatch` an action. This can either be done via a click of a button or something else entirely. You should update your `start` function to be along the lines of the following

```
const start = request => {
  const action = {
    type: 'UPDATE',
    request
  };

  dispatch(action);
}
```

The `dispatch(action)` will cause an update to the state that will be available on render.

Comment: Correct.  I left that out of this example for brevity.  I am currently updating the state in both the start and end functions.  I am wanting to get access to the current state inside of the start and end functions

Comment: I am currently having the same issue... my state updates inside the reducer well but not inside my component... did you figure out why?