# state not reflected in arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Similar question posted on [Arrow functions only have access to initial state created by useReducer, not updated state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57279320/arrow-functions-only-have-access-to-initial-state-created-by-usereducer-not-upd) but not resolved.

The state (useReducer) is not reflected in arrow functions.

A simple example:
React component

```js
const Component = ({ children }: Props) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {visitor: false})

 useEffect(() => {
    someObject = new Connection({
    onMessage: msg
    onSuccess: () => dispatch({type: "Visitor", value: true})
    })
    return () => console.log("UNMOUNTING ");
  }, []);

    const msg = (request) => {
        // visitor: false
        console.log(state) // expected updated state, but instead see initial state, why?
        // ... do more things
    }
    // visitor: true
    console.log(state) // updated state is present here
    return (
        <Component.Provider value={{ state }}>
            {children}
        </Component.Provider>
    )
}
```

Reducer function:

```js
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'Visitor':
          return {...state, visitor: true}
        default:
          return state
    }
}
```

Comment: its as if the callback function is pointing to the original state variable somehow ?

Comment: The old state is `const` and will never update. The re-render will get the new state, but not run the effect again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a callback to `useEffect` on component mount, this callback has a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on `state` value `{visitor: false}`.

```
// Closure on `state = {visitor: false}` passed to useEffect
useEffect(() => {
  msg();
}, [])
```